# It’s time to retire the term “rep-whore”

Tags: discussion, reputation, be-nice-policy

Going forward, “rep-whore” (and its derivatives) will be treated like any other term that’s inconsistent with the community’s  “be nice” policy: it will be removed.

## It’s totally okay if you’ve used it in the past.

Nobody’s judging the many users who’ve used it. And users will NOT start being suspended/banned/fed-to-the-Sarlaac for using it in the near future without knowing about the change.  We’re all partly products of what’s “normal” in our environment, and for a long time, use of that term *was* normal, and intended as a shorthand for “users who know a behavior is harmful, but do it anyway, entirely because it generates rep.”  It was used - without malice - by good-hearted users in lots of old posts. It has probably been used by employees occasionally in the past. There’s no shame or judgment implied here; it’s just time to recognize that it's not consistent with "be nice.” And its use actually undermines our ability to get the most out of needed discussions on user behavior, incentives, etc.  To be clear, it *is* absolutely okay to talk about *specific behaviors* that may represent unintended consequences of the rep-based feedback loop, and to continue to question them - just don’t do it by name-calling.

## The short version of the "why"

- It’s inconsistent with our “be nice" policy:

  - It’s vulgar, and may be construed as being gendered (albeit not intentionally, in my observations).
  - The term makes the problem about the *person, not the action*.  (And it doesn’t help to verbify it as “rep-whoring” - that’s still only describing it as something a person-type would do, vs. a specific thing that was done.)
- Naming “user types” with pejorative terms tends to lead to over-use of those terms, and undermines actual dialogue that might help us better understand what's going wrong.

That really covers it.  But we like to be as open as possible about our underlying thinking, so if you're curious, or have a lot of time to kill...

## The longer version

**The term clearly doesn't jibe with “being nice”:**
Here are the relevant parts of the [Be Nice policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice):

> - No Name Calling -  Focus on the post, not the person. That includes terms that feel personal even when they're applied to posts (like "lazy", "ignorant", or "whiny").*
> - Rudeness and belittling language are not okay.
> - Avoid vulgar terms and anything sexually suggestive.
> - Be welcoming, be patient, and **assume good intentions** (emphasis mine)

Frankly, those are good enough reasons - this community has always been fairly united in our commitment to discuss problems openly, **but with strong commitment to respect and courtesy, and a focus on the content or  behavior, not the person.**

So, even if this term *were* super-useful in helping us solve problems and improve the site, I think most folks here would agree that we shouldn’t be scrapping big chunks of our “be nice” policy just for the sake of expediency.  But here’s the funny thing:

**Using terms like “rep-whore” tends to *undermine* our ability to break down situations and learn where the system does have real problems or unintended consequences.**

**Labeling users with names that almost no one would call themselves reduces two-sided discourse and learning.**  We actually learn the most when we listen to those who *don’t* agree with us (yet, anyway - I like to think they’ll eventually come around).  But when we say, “the problem is rep-whores,” to explain someone answering questions that we think should be closed instead, it reduces the number of folks motivated to say, “Oh, hey - I guess I’m one of those ‘rep-whores’.  Is that what you call someone who just answers questions when they can, but doesn’t keep track of what’s on- and off-topic?”   Note that I’m *not* saying that’s usually the actual case, but the problem is that we'd never know if it were. By just describing it as “rep-whoring,” we've cut off much hope of learning if another motivation might apply - we’ve *assumed* we know the motivation, and given it a nasty name, so any users involved who might wish to actually explain their motivations don’t even think we're talking about (non-whore-esque) folks like them.

**There’s a funny thing about *naming* something.**  Once a thing has a name, you tend to start seeing it everywhere. That's part of the positive power of language: by giving a complex thing a shorthand term, it’s easier to identify it quickly, just by matching a couple of key variables.  Heuristics like that are what let us function at higher efficiency.  But they come with costs: false positives and loss of nuance.  The entire *point* of these types of categorization is to allow faster pattern matching, with fewer inputs and less analysis.  But that means that things with *some* shared attributes, or even just similar ones, can get (wrongly) lumped in buckets pretty quickly.

Which is how we find ourselves making assumptions about others.  I may think:

> “Someone who answers a question that we’d normally close is obviously only motivated by rep, and clearly doesn't care that it’s hurting the site.”

Maybe. Maybe they *are* only motivated by rep. Or maybe it’s something else:  Maybe they don’t know (or care) what’s on-topic; they choose to answer questions where they can help, but don’t want to have to also serve as a filter for what’s currently allowed.

Personally, *I* happen to think that’s okay. I’m actually good with the idea that helping here doesn't require, “helping in all the ways, including ones you don’t enjoy.”  Now, you may not agree, and think it’s a problem. That's good! And if that were the situation, *that’s* what we need to be talking about.  But by ascribing the problems to “rep-whores,” I’ve eliminated that fact-finding step, and potentially even *prevented* us from getting to some of the real issues that we might want to discuss, all to save a few minutes by slapping a convenient name on the situation.

**Caring about getting lots of rep is a little like caring about getting lots of money - it seems to be a problem that is only diagnosed as afflicting *other people.*** Posts about rep-whores are pretty consistently written by folks who say they’re *not* at all motivated by rep - that *they* would only do things for more altruistic reasons.  Which… I happen to believe is true. I think almost all of them *are actually motivated by the desire to help, or to contribute to a useful resource.*  So here’s the question: given that we know *we’d* only choose behaviors if we thought they were good for the site, why are we so quick to assume that rep is the *primary* driver of others’ behavior, regardless of the harm it might cause?  I think part of it may be what's apparently known as the  [actor–observer asymmetry/bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor%E2%80%93observer_asymmetry).  The gist is this - when *you* swerve your car without warning, you know you’re a responsible driver coping as best you can with challenging circumstances - you saw something in the road, or your kid finally succeeded in pitching a gummy bear into your ear. But when you see someone *else* swerve their car, you assume they’re a bad driver.  Or texting.  Or drunk.

**In conclusion…**
Let’s keep talking about rep, and unintended consequences. To be honest, we *want* people to care about it, but not *too* much, and not as an end unto itself.  Rep *is* supposed to be motivating, largely as a feedback loop.  It's designed to confirm that you’re achieving what you all really came here to do:  share your experiences in way that generates a resource that will actually make a difference. That little green "+10" is a proxy for someone saying, "that was useful".  Your effort here mattered.  So it’s okay to like getting it. I do.  But it’s also okay - in fact it’s important - to call out places where it may be over-incentivizing things we don’t want.  Let's just do it without using terms that’ll make Julia Roberts sad:

[image]

**For now, don’t worry about purging old uses of the term.**
This isn’t intended to create a lot of new work, particularly for mods, so we don’t want folks searching through tons of old posts and throwing up hundreds of flags. But if you run into new uses of the term, treat em like any other thing inconsistent with “be nice” (edit ‘em out when possible, etc.)

Comment: Let's erase all the offensive words from dictionary, this world would become a better place </sarcasm>

Comment: TBH, changing something that's this heavily ingrained into the very culture of the sites is a longshot at best. If you're gonna force it by means of banning people, expect to lose a lot well-respected users.

Comment: @Mystical I don't think anyone would argue that the cultural component can be snap-changed, but as with any social change, the first step is awareness.

Comment: @Emrakul I have a hunch that bringing awareness might actually trigger the [Streisand effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streisand_effect) which could actually *increase* its usage. It's not like everyone knows what the term is. It's mostly localized to long-time users. But if you try to massively publicize it (like in the title of a post)... well...

Comment: @Mystical Maybe in the short term. It's like gay marriage - when it started to become a public issue, people became more aware and openly insistent about what they felt was right, on both sides - but respect for others will win out in the long run.

Comment: Finally. Nice to see this shift.

Comment: @Emrakul I see your point. If the goal here is to turn "repwhore" into a racial slur that goes through a something like a civil rights movement before it finally disappears. Go for it. That definitely won't happen overnight. But it would work out the best if it succeeds.

Comment: I mean, I don't think we need to *ban* it. But I agree that there is a definite derogatory connotation, and we should avoid using it as such.

Comment: I also worry about what using a derogatory term for a prostitute to refer to someone who wants a lot of something (be it sex, reputation or something else) *implies*, exactly.

Comment: @Mysticial - It isn't like this is an overnight change. Stack Overflow moderators have been telling people that we're uncomfortable with that term for years, and it's been a one-click-delete trigger for at least the last several months: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/325996/19679 http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313790/can-i-know-why-commentary-was-deleted-on-this-question#comment289889_313849 . At least from what I've seen, when people are nudged away from using the term, that tends to stick.

Comment: The rationale implies that the term "rep farmer" should also be _verboten_.

Comment: I used the term in a meta post yesterday, I have already edited it out.

Comment: Fantastic news! That's the first time I have seen that term and I am glad to see its use removed.

Comment: I do not recall any examples where the term was applied to an identifiable person, rather than descrbing a pattern of behaviour of an otherwise not identified group of users.

Comment: Can you please add what can be used instead? People love shortcuts, especially programmers. :)

Comment: These rep-hunters, I really don't like them much. :)

Comment: "*Caring about getting lots of rep is a little like caring about getting lots of money - it seems to be a problem that is only diagnosed as afflicting **other people**.*" Sorry, this is completely mistaken. I used to refer to myself as being obsessed with rep all the time, and still regularly call myself a "former rep maniac" (though I've been self-censoring myself on the W-word for a while now). To judge from comments about this post here and elsewhere, I'm by far not the only one who applies such terms and attributes such motivations to *themselves*.

Comment: @randal'thor which is fine, just don't use it for other people

Comment: The idea that erasing a word from the community's allowed vocabulary would make discussions somehow more productive and "nicer" is completely absurd. Using labels to identify and categorize users who we *can't* treat cordially, who have *demonstrated* they are on the site for the wrong reason, and form the *antithesis of a content-, rather than people-based **repository of knowledge*** allows us to effectively talk about these problem users and find solutions to the problems related to their existence. Marking problems as problems isn't offensive, it's honest and it's above all *productive*.

Comment: On meta we need to talk about people and their problems assuming good intention until proven otherwise.

Comment: There are so many feature requests which should be prioritized *so* much higher than this which are getting no attention, and this is, apparently, what Stack Overflow, Inc chooses to pursue. If you can control the language used in the discussion, you can control the discussion, I guess, and it's time to rein in the users a little more.  Got to slowly bring the users around to this company's beliefs about words and word usage. ***DOUBLE PLUS UNGOOD***

Comment: What about "help vampires"?

Comment: @TylerH this term is probably on it's way to [SE version of Seven Dirty Words](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238835/165773) too. "Help vampire" goes too much against current party line to ["focus on pleasing question askers..."](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254973/839601) (just in case if Shog comes and buries this discussion into chat room - don't forget to upvote his comment declaring that move, to [help folks see the way](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279458/165773) and re-upvote all critical messages in that chat room)

Comment: @gnat Agreed. Based on what I've been seeing for the past few years, SO/SE has been increasingly desperate to shed the whole "SO is negative" image to outsiders. And they're getting to the point that they're willing to try *anything* - including alienating the very users who are providing the content that run the site. Sure little things like banning +/-1 or keywords like repwhore/vampire may be small, but it does add up in the long run. At some point, people are gonna start snapping. (i.e. YCS) And when that happens, the very users that were once valued become trolls.

Comment: So, I finally dug up the context for the comment ban from two years back, @Mysticial. Turns out, there was a group of people hanging out in chat who liked to descend upon answers to questions they didn't care for, downvote regardless of merit, and throw out these vitriolic comments to try to discourage them from answering. So you got folks with thousands of answers to their name - literally "the very users who are providing the content" - being attacked by a group of bar-flies who've already given up. And you're concerned that *discouraging vitriol* is gonna drive folks away?

Comment: (4 - 5) that's not the real problem

Comment: @Shog9: I wasn't aware that we'd already been mulling this over for 2 years.

Comment: At least that, @Robert. Go search the blue room - looks like Tim & bluefeet brought this to my attention back in Spring of '14.

Comment: Good to see you jumped right on it then lol ;)

Comment: Well, I banned it shortly thereafter, @Lightness. Then kinda forgot about it until Tim & Jay brought it up again the other day.

Comment: How is "debase oneself by doing something for unworthy motives, typically to make money" vulgar? - Derogatory? yes, as it should be. Vulgar? no. (IMO, you can use the verb to denote the action but you cannot, *as always*, call each other names with nouns)

Comment: For what it's worth, for all those people saying they've never seen a _user_ called this before, I ran a search on a few sites, and found a few comments _explicitly_ calling another user a rep-whore.

Comment: “Don’t step on the toes of the dog lovers, the cat lovers, doctors, lawyers, merchants, chiefs, Mormons, Baptists, Unitarians, second-generation Chinese, Swedes, Italians, Germans, Texans, Brooklynites, Irishmen, people from Oregon or Mexico... The bigger your market, Montag, the less you handle controversy, remember that!" - Ray Bradbury (Fahrenheit 451).

Comment: And the next one will be "It's time to retire the phrasing “[don't migrate crap!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/82986/312017)”"…

Comment: I'm quite saddened and confused by these actions. When you venture outside of the SO/SE community, these are not the things people complain about. I've had lengthly debates with people who become disheartened and upset over their questions beind closed, marked as duplicate and various other issues that have nothing to do with the words we use. So what do we do? We focus on making sure our own communities _feelings_ aren't hurt.. for shame. For shame..

Comment: Amazing that you don't mention the unniceness to women of a misogynistic term.

Comment: Would you mind unpacking the opaque cultural reference so that it isn't necessary to spend 1 hour and 59 minutes watching a film to figure out what you mean?

Comment: @PeterTaylor, first off, let me assure you that if you watch Pretty Woman for the first time, understanding my nonsense is the *least* of the benefits you'll get. It's delightful, like most things Julia Roberts is in! In this context, I was just making a silly reference to the fact that in the movie, Julia Roberts' character has the most conflict and tension in situations when someone calls her something that indicates that she is involved in prostitution. (It's actually not literally the word "whore," but she bristles at two different synonyms for it.)

Comment: FWIW, I've been on the SE network since, uh, just after this post was first published in 2016 I think. I'd never heard of this term until this post got bumped today. If you're trying to disincentivize using a term that was apparently used an awful lot back in the day, maybe consider editing the post so that the term isn't in big letters on the home page?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Yeah... This seems like a good idea. The term has moved from its original jocular uses to something considerably more mean-spirited. I suspect most folks using the term now have some sort of nasty boogieman in mind rather than [good ol' Marc Gravell](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15540/award-bounties-at-the-end-of-the-day/15553#15553).

And [when folks here are more concerned about what other people think of them](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254549/how-to-decide-which-questions-i-should-not-answer) than they are about programming, I think the term becomes decidedly counter-productive, no less a distraction than rep itself.

FWIW, "whore" has triggered fast deletion on flagged comments for quite a while, and has been banned outright on Stack Overflow for over two years *because* it was being used to harass people:

[image]

Comment: how's this thing implemented?

Comment: It's implemented *on a different site*...

Comment: I have mixed feelings about this whole thing.  I don't have any problem at all with banning the term "whore"  network-wide, even though I think the whole clbuttic pr0blem is a whack-a-mole.  What does disturb me a bit, though, is the "thought police" mentality that seems to have crept into SE.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - I'm surprised to hear you say that. One of the primary roles of moderators on the Stack Exchange network has always been to make sure people are treated with respect. This and other recent code of conduct announcements have been merely codifying informal policies that we've applied for years. This isn't "thought police", it's just formally stating policy on behaviors that many people have believed were inappropriate for a long time. Every person visiting these sites deserves to be treated with respect, and rudeness in comments reflects badly on every contributor here.

Comment: @BradLarson: It's kind of hard to explain. This decision is a by-product of *SE's obsession with inclusiveness.*  SE doesn't interpret new visitors asking flagrantly off-topic questions without making any attempt at learning the first thing about the site or its culture as rudeness, so we put in word filters but never solve the underlying problems.

Comment: @BradLarson it would be nice if this would work. [But it doesn't](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281787/it-s-time-to-retire-the-term-rep-whore#comment915375_281807), "how come that after years of plugging user's mouths and twisting their arms with summers of love and hunting the snark the second top question at MSO is 'Why is Stack Overflow so negative of late?'"

Comment: @BradLarson I think Robert hit the nail here. It's not the word that were're all raging about. Nor is it merely a matter of just being rude vs. nice. Or course it's better to be nice. Of course calling people a whore is rude. It's the fact that SE is slowly trying to control the way we think. That crosses the line for a lot of people.

Comment: Ok, as much as I enjoy 1984/Newspeak references, this is a bit of an exaggeration, @Mysticial. Generally-speaking, folks aren't calling *askers* whores; this is directed at *answerers*. So we slowly build up this culture of... Well, bullying. Not, "what did you see of value in this question" or "edit unclear questions if you want to answer them" or even "please don't answer blatantly off-topic questions", but "don't repwhore". It becomes a bad-apple problem: the folks who've already given up participating trying to ruin it for the folks who haven't.

Comment: @Shog9 I wonder why those *folks* gave up participating. Perhaps we should focus on that?

Comment: Directing people how to behave in comments (politely or not) is a waste of time anyway.  I've been doing this for awhile, and I could probably count on the fingers of both hands the times someone actually took my advice.

Comment: Which is why I've become fond of these blacklists, @Robert. Folks hate 'em of course, but they've been surprisingly effective when it comes to discouraging "monkey see, monkey do".

Comment: Kinda makes this whole meta post a tempest in a teapot, doesn't it?  You could have just quietly added the word to the blacklist and avoided this whole kerfluffle.  It's not like Jaydles is asking the community whether we should do it or not.

Comment: Really, @Shoe? "Someone's unhappy and lashing out at others - let's not ask them to stop until we've tried everything possible to appease them". You try that with a 3-year-old, you find that now they throw a tantrum *every* time they're in the checkout lane. And programmers can be almost as savvy as 3-year-olds.

Comment: Well, apparently I did that two years ago @Robert. But this is meta; we gotta talk about things here, even when we'd rather not. Otherwise, there's no point.

Comment: @Shoe: [We do have other remedies](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) for folks like that.

Comment: And the comment got censored because it contained the N-word. I guess that proves my point. Just mindlessly censoring everything that looks bad without taking a look at the context.

Comment: @Shoe: That word is probably in the black list.  One flag from the community can dispatch it.

Comment: Yes, it does, @shoe. What, did you not know that we censor overt racism? Not as part of some grand scheme to stop racism, but because it's vile and has no value to what we do here. Also, please don't try any more "clever" replies (what next? Implying we don't censor overt sexism? Attacks on religion?) - if you got a point, you can make it without turning this into a thread that's gonna be uncomfortable for arbitrary groups to read.

Comment: @Shog9 The word here was clearly not meant to be racist. It was an example of a context where banning words doesn't really help the underlying issue.

Comment: Yeah. You just threw it out there as an example of a word with a long history of being used to hurt and belittle people that *you* should be able to use in other contexts because... Just stop. I don't know what your point was other than to derail this thread, @Shoe, but you've at least accomplished that. Congratulations. Now go sit in the car.

Comment: _"Now go sit in the car"_ Yeah because that's being nice and treating people with respect. smh

Comment: You're kinda four years too late on this, @andrew.

Answer (score 154):

### TL;DR:

Please don't just try to cure the symptoms when curing the cancer is this simple.

Retract reputation gained from questions that are closed (or that were closed within a certain time frame, starting with the creation of the question), and you'll most likely fix this whole rep-system-abuse that's been going on for **way too long.**

---

When I first read the title I was feeling happy. I felt excited. Simply because I thought to myself "Hey, they're changing something! Maybe it'll put an end to all the rep-vampires!".. But no. All you're doing is banning a term that has been used for ages, because it's pejorative.

### Congrats.

**Yes**, this term is pejorative. **And yes**, it is negative. **And yes**, it - just going by the wording - does target the person instead of the action. **And yes**, it is highly unprofessional. **And yes**, that is a problem. But it's not **the problem!**

*Note: I highly support banning this term, I just don't think that it'll change anything on its own, except for frustrating people even more.*

Why do terms like this exist? Why are users calling other users out for *"rep-whoring"*, *"rep-chasing"* and other terms? Because it's an **actual problem that has to be dealt with.** So instead of just straight-up banning the term what you could've done instead is taking care of the problem.

### How?

Retract reputation gained from questions closed for specific reasons. It's that simple. It would end the [FGITW-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/fastest-gun/info), it'd prevent the usage of terms like "rep-whore" (simply because the action that "rep-whore" describes is no longer existent), and it shouldn't be that hard to implement, whereas solely enforcing a term-ban would do two things:

1. It'd certainly cost you a part of your user base. I don't think I'll have to explain why.
2. It'd require a lot of resources. I burn through a lot of flags everyday, I'm present in the SOCVR-room & I do a lot to keep this site clean from trash, spam and the like, but I don't want to hunt down a certain term, and, taking into account how long this term has been used, it'd be a lot of usages to hunt down.

### Why is this such a big problem?

Because it defies the purpose of this network. Stack Exchange is supposed to be a Q&A-network, right? The ultimate goal is to have a collection of every possible question, alongside with the correct answer. In order to have a collection of that size you'll have to filter out the garbage, and that's what a lot of people are doing by using the tools given to them, flags, close votes and hammers.

Reputation on the other hand is the currency of this network. It depicts - to a certain extent - how much "trust" you've gained, and how much effort you've put into this project. However, thanks to people answering questions FGITW-style, this currency loses its meaning.

(*Side-note: I am not talking about new users. I try to explain them the system that Stack Exchange is based on, and move on. I'm talking about the high-rep users that do this knowingly, as in answering known duplicates, off-topic questions, and so on.*)

In my opinion these people are actively damaging the Stack Exchange network.
The reputation system is getting abused, and yet they can continue what they're doing. All I can do in this case is downvote it, but - in most cases - the OP has already upvoted & accepted that answer, so my downvote does what? Lower his rep gain from 25 (Upvote + Accept) to 23? To be honest, I can't be bothered.

Comment: I largely agree. Instead of (or in addition to) banning the pejorative, let's *actually fix the problem*. Not giving rep on closed posts would be a fantastic step.

Comment: Note that the question says "...it’s also okay - in fact it’s important - to call out places where [reputation] may be over-incentivizing things we don’t want. Let's just do it without using terms that’ll make Julia Roberts sad." If there's a big problem, say so! Just do it without using an offensive term :)

Comment: You tricked me into downvoting for a sec while I read your intro :) -1 for supporting getting rid of the word +2 for proposing that it's replaced with an actual solution to the problem. The phrase doesn't matter as long as there is an attempt to fix the problem in SE, which there hasn't been so far.

Comment: This is the solution to the root problem. I hope this is considered as there will be plenty of other problems resulting from playing wack-a-mole with all the problems resulting from FGITW and answering questions which ultimately end up closed.

Comment: Kinda conflicted on this. On the one hand, removing rep from closed posts (or at least rep from voting - essentially the rep-denial part of CW without the mixed-message) would solve a lot of problems *even if it did nothing to discourage the problem you're concerned about*. On the other hand, it feels like punting; we should probably just be deleting more of these.

Comment: @Shog9 I agree with you on this. But I think there's potentially two parts here: 1) The ones that *should* be deleted aren't because the barrier to deletion is too high. 2) When they *are* deleted, the people losing the rep may not be getting the message they should stop answering crap. I don't know what the numbers are, but if the roomba kicks in 1 month later, the person probably won't be aware of what's going on - let alone know to avoid bad questions.

Comment: @Shog9 the reason they don't get deleted is because questions with an answer that picked up a few upvotes isn't roomba'ed. If you make it so there is less incentive to answer them, more would get roombaed.

Comment: IOW, if we want people to stop answering bad questions, we need to both take away the incentive *and* to communicate it properly.

Comment: The communication thing sounds like the missing piece here, @Mysticial. I feel like we wait waaay too long to give folks a heads-up that they're answering something sketchy. I'm skeptical that doing anything after the answer is posted will produce good results, but there may be a window of time *before* that would do some good...

Comment: @Shog9 how about giving a [heads-up to folks that they're answering a possible duplicate](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/316638/839601)? "...a modal popup to the answerer if the question is voted / flagged as duplicate.

With the link (or better yet, full text) of possible duplicate and a message like: There is possible duplicate here, please make sure that you don't repeat already existing answers..."

Comment: @Shog9 Do you have statistics on whether the first dupe-vote comes in before or after the first answer?

Comment: Not handy; could probably dig some up if you wanna start a separate discussion somewhere @Mysticial.

Comment: Retracting rep gained on closed dupes would be a good start.

Comment: @Iain [hardly so](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316564/remove-the-incentive-for-fgitw-to-answer-well-known-dupes#comment305914_316564 "'if this was ever implemented... you'd end up with a lot less people voting to close duplicates (because then people would lose some rep!) or even reopening clear duplicates that they've answered and had upvoted. This could easily backfire to the point that less duplicates end up (and stay) actually closed'")... unfortunately

Comment: @Mysticial [stats are here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/316682/839601): "Median time to first close flag or vote: 7 minutes
Median time to answer: 6 minutes". [Quoting self](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/28709235#28709235), _even with hands tied behind their backs, voters almost catch up ("7-vs-6"). If you shift gameplay a bit on their side, things will likely change, there will be more chances for flags to get there before answers_

Comment: @Shog9 ^^^ is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Oh, that's why this sounded familiar. Bother.

Comment: @Shog9: "we should probably just be deleting more of these" Are there any plans to get [delete vote review queues](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148204), or is there some other strategy for more effectively deleting old, low-quality closed posts that for one reason or another are immune to auto-deletion?

Comment: There is one for 10K users, @sumelic. It's old and... Has some major problems. Big question is, what should feed a new one? Presumably *not* everything that gets closed... Some will be auto-deleted, some will probably be reopened... So maybe stuff that goes through reopen review *n* times? Honestly, this has been nagging at me for about 4 years now; I know it needs to be done, but it's gonna be probably an even bigger headache than close review.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265165/rewarding-overzealous-users-for-answering-duplicate-questions-is-undermining-the

Comment: this answer is exemplary and worthy of an additional bounty: "Please don't just try to cure the symptoms when curing the cancer is this simple". Helps to understand why such a _nice_ looking announcement has got 49 downvotes

Comment: **The incentive structure is the reification of the will of the organisation.**  If the organisation _wanted_ to identify duplicates, _there would be a positive incentive to do that_. As it stands, the organisation does not wish to identify duplicates, it merely pretends to want to do that, because that would put off a segment of users, and they make their money selling ad impressions.

Answer (score 55):

> It's time...

...it's time to keep the [promise](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/320971/839601) made three months ago:

> we'll start looking at [increasing the number of close votes based on rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266500/proposal-to-make-close-votes-scale-with-rep)

You seem to be blaming users for unnecessary rudeness and trying to cut their ways to express it. That may be true and right, but if you think of it the [root cause](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/154741/31260) for their attitude may lie elsewhere.

For example, if many inappropriate questions aren't closed quickly enough and this makes a wide open door for answers to leak into them, it may cause negative feelings for those who care about content quality. If this is the case, banning particular negative terms won't help. The negative feelings will stay; people will simply invent other terms to express them, and things won't really get nicer.

I think it's time to look closer at these things in the historical perspective.

For example, how come that after years of plugging users' mouths and twisting their arms with *summers of love* and *hunting the snark*, the second-highest-voted question at MSO is [Why is Stack Overflow so **negative** of late?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251758/839601) Makes one wonder if this way works, doesn't it?

---

You see, negative feelings (and their respective terms) may simply indicate that a community lacks power and tools to protect itself from inappropriate content.

I heard that the author who best explained these matters is a member of Stack Exchange's board of directors -- ([Clay Shirky](http://www.shirky.com/writings/group_enemy.html)) -- maybe it's time to have a word with him.

> thing you have to accept: Members are different than users. A pattern will arise in which there is some group of users that cares more than average about the integrity and success of the group as a whole. And that becomes your core group, Art Kleiner's phrase for "the group within the group that matters most."
>
> The core group... was undifferentiated from the group of random users that came in. They were separate in their own minds, because they knew what they wanted to do, but they couldn't defend themselves against the other users. But in all successful online communities that I've looked at, a core group arises that cares about and gardens effectively. Gardens the environment, to keep it growing, to keep it healthy.
>
> Now, the software does not always allow the core group to express itself, which is why I say you have to accept this. Because if the software doesn't allow the core group to express itself, it will invent new ways of doing so...

I think it would be very **nice** of you to pay a bit more attention to the [concerns of your core group](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254973/839601).

Comment: @bjb568, it's fine if you don't like the "be nice" policy. It's also fine to argue that it's a bad policy, and that we should be happy to trade being respectful to each other for being more effective.  But it's *not* fine to ignore it deliberately.  Kindly re-phrase your comment.

Comment: @Jaydles I have no issue with the "be nice" policy. I fully uphold it as something every member of the community should abide by. But treating SE as a social media site that focuses on users rather than content bugs me. I fail to see how my comment above violates any site policies or in any way negatively affects the site. In any case, I can't edit the comment past 5 minutes.

Comment: Finding issue with common phrases that people use constructively and further assuming non-abidance to site rules because someone uses the phrase in a discussion about the phrase itself is not rational. Behavior like this by the leaders of the community is what misguidedly drives the community into destructive actions and changes like the summer of love.

Comment: @Jaydles I for one _like_ the "be nice" policy. It could help me brag about my posts on programming topics without fear that folks looking at the site will find it polluted with rude / snarky comments. What I don't like is that policy doesn't seem to work, "how come that after years of plugging user's mouths and twisting their arms with summers of love and hunting the snark the second top question at MSO is 'Why is Stack Overflow so negative of late?'"

Comment: Completely agree. Give those who care the means to (more) efficiently close/delete whatever needs that action. You won't have to deal with perceived problematic behaviour if you take the opportunity for it to spawn away. And maybe that even means custom measures for some of the smaller sites. Large communities can count on large active user-bases, but what works there may not apply to some of the smaller sites within the network.

Comment: On SO we have effectively lost the ability to dupe close and prevent this. I max out anyone's real rep at 50K because that is probably all they have done for the site anyway. Mainly because I am not so fixated on the rep thing. Why others are is beyond me.

Comment: As the question says: "...it’s also okay - in fact it’s important - to call out places where [reputation] may be over-incentivizing things we don’t want. Let's just do it without using terms that’ll make Julia Roberts sad."

Comment: @Jefromi I "called out" these places [about 35K times](http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats "36127 close reviews as of now") in last two years. I did it completely within terms and means provided by Stack Exchange system, without any trace of negativity in comments, I did nothing that could make Julia Roberts sad. Now I wonder how come that it continues and seems to only get worse

Comment: Context for the top few comments: There are deleted comments here and a lengthy discussion about them in Tavern on the Meta.

Comment: I want to be pretty clear that fixing things that actively deter people from contributing and fixing the root causes of them aren't necessarily mutually exclusive. We're not going to say "everyone just stop saying rep whore" and call it a day, we're going to continue working to make sure _your_ experience isn't frustrating, too. The quality project is something we kick off every year and a half, where we look at what we did last time, how usage patterns evolved, and we hone in on what else we can do - that's coming up again soon and we've already got a lot of ideas [1/2]

Comment: I'll be posting about this probably within the next two weeks, defining some pretty clear goals we want to meet, and setting a timeline to execute against those goals. No one is ignoring the fact that our most engaged users get frustrated by also worrying about users we can't engage due to perceived rudeness or hostility, this is just an opportunity to cut back on the latter which we're taking now. [2/2]

Comment: @TimPost what about the promise to start looking at increasing the number of close votes based on rep?

Comment: @gnat That's one of the things in scope this time. Along with a more guided version of the ask question page that very new users will see, and a bunch of other stuff we wanted to do last time but scope just got so crazy.

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to scale close votes to close vote experience. The new influx of rep producing Docs would just shove gnat down the pecking order potentially, and others up, that don't even use it. I for one find the new rep producing "thing" to be a potential boom for closing though. It will be interesting.

Comment: Yes, I'm firmly looking at scaling based on _efficacy_ of voting. I think I'll kick open a discussion about it, now that it's firmly back in my mind. Post coming!

Comment: @Drew as much as I would be happy to tell that scaling votes to close experience is the way to go, last experiment has shown that [this is unlikely to work](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319131/1-2-3-test-let-s-increase-the-number-of-reviews-close-votes-for-science/320971#comment333024_320971). Closing this way means one would review in unfamiliar tags and this seems to be causing reviewer fatigue at 50-60 votes a day. Extra close votes would better go to users active in particular tag, because to them it would probably be easier to use these _within their tag_ (more organically)

Comment: I am delighted at the prospect of more close voters. I would also say that some of us can handle 100 a day somedays. It is major burnout as we are recruiters for it anyway and see it. We get 3 weeks of interest, then if fades. I also don't see much correlation of experience (rep)  gained by Docs rep and determining what should close. That being, a topic opening a whole can of worms. But that is above my pay grade and I will take the good with the bad.

Comment: Discussion started here: [Is using reputation to scale the number of close votes the best way?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281818/is-scaling-the-number-of-close-votes-based-on-rep-the-best-way-to-scale-them)

Comment: would be interesting to hear from (10) users who voted this down. Quoting Robert Harvey, "For those of you who are downvoting, there's clearly something here you disagree with. While you're certainly in no way obligated to explain your downvotes here or anywhere else, this _is_ a meta site. The purpose of meta sites is discussion, and it might be useful if you articulated your concerns. I can only imagine that you fundamentally disagree with the premise of my answer, unless you don't like my tone. Either way, it would be nice to know."

Comment: @TimPost where's the post? :( no activity http://stackexchange.com/users/20808/tim-post?tab=activity

Comment: @TimPost, 2 years later, Is the post promised above any nearer completion?

Answer (score 23):

This feels a bit like [bowdlerisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Bowdler). I've *personally* avoided it and favour the term 'Power Gamer' or 'Bounty Hunter' (drawing from my mispent youth as a pen and paper gamer).
To me the 'be nice' policy isn't about language use. It's about ensuring that as many of my users (as a mod) feel as comfortable as possible, and I've almost never seen the term used as such.

I've never seen anyone actually *use* the term 'repwhore' in anger. It's used in terms of 'repwhorage' in some situations. (Interestingly, the term's been only used 6 times on Root Access. Mostly by me, referring to me. I encourage others to try this on, and it's been used 4 times on meta SU -- this isn't exactly common.) It might be different on other sites.

I feel 'be nice' is not about the *words*; it's about the *actions* and *overall intent*. If someone on a site I'm seeing went "hey, I'm not comfortable with someone calling me a repwhore" I'd obviously encourage the person who used that term to be more *precise* over what issues they have are. If someone called themselves a repwhore, or referred to an answer as repwhorage, it's a very different thing,

So, I think the solution here might not be to worry about the *term*. If it needs to be gone, encouraging *precision* and *focusing on the actions* is good moderation.

So as a mod, it feels like it's an attempt to solve a non existent problem. We can simply deal with people not being nice for its own sake without declaring war on a phrase.

Comment: @randalthor Intent matters a great deal, but not all language can be excused by good intent. Some things just don't feel good to hear, no matter how the speaker intended them.

Comment: @Jefromi I tend to disagree - and I feel this is the most balanced opposing viewpoint to this. I must admit, *part* of my issues seem to be something like this is counter to the general spirit of self-regulation many sites have. I'd also note, I could not have gotten my point across without using that term - which mildly annoyed me to be fair.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek The only really solid absolute policy here is "don't say this thing which is offensive but somehow was tolerated for a long time." The rest is guidance about how to be extra nice; if you feel you need a label still, as long as you don't use a blatantly offensive one, you're not going to be stopped from getting your point across.

Comment: To address your answer more directly: I don't think this is bowderization, because the term was already making a lot of people uncomfortable. I know the people using it didn't see it that way, and so like Jaydles' original post I don't want to blame them for it, but that doesn't really change how it sounds to readers. That is, the intent excuses the unknowing offense, but it can't excuse deliberate ongoing offense.

Comment: @Jefromi: "It's not bowdlerization if people are actually uncomfortable"? Really? That's amusing.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I fail to see what's amusing about the notion of people hurting other people's feelings, possibly knowingly.

Comment: @NathanTuggy "Bowlderization" has strong connotations of impairing effective discourse, and unnecessary removal of language. That's not really the case here - we're talking about a term that actually causes offense, and was being used to harass people, and a concept which can be easily discussed without that term. Still, I was careful to say that I don't blame people for using it in the past! And... if you want to mock that kind of thing as "public morals", well, keep in mind that you're on a site with a Be Nice policy. We've chosen to enforce rules about how people treat each other.

Comment: @Jefromi: I don't *object* to it, as long as people are honest about it and aren't painting themselves as somehow above those in the past who made awfully similar choices. Also, there actually have been a number of people here making fairly persuasive arguments that this is a concept that needs to be discussed, not censored -- especially given that trivial replacements of "rep whore" are likely to prove just as problematic and will thus get banned as well. So yes: this is in fact almost exactly the same thing, all the way down to some people being legitimately offended.

Comment: Okay, well if you define bowlderization to be the process of stopping people from saying things that legitimately offend others, then yes, this is bowlderization (and much of Be Nice is too). I'm not sure that's how it was meant in this answer, though. And discussion of the concept is most certainly not banned. Even the OP says that it's fine to discuss rep and unintended consequences. It's things like "user X is clearly Y just to get rep" that you want to be careful about, but even then, you're certainly not going to get flat-out censored.

Answer (score -1):

- **People are supposed to be seeking rep.**
- **If people seeking rep are doing the "wrong things", you are giving rep for the "wrong things".**
- **The main "wrong thing" is duplicates which are *answered* instead of *closed as duplicates*.**

Flagging a duplicate gets no rep.

Answering "how to make teh join" or "fix this pivot for me" will get you 50 points even though it is an exact duplicate.

That's the problem you need to fix:

- Add 10 Rep for everyone voting to close as duplicate (when subsequently closed).
- Negative rep for answering when the question is later flagged as a duplicate

Then people will stop doing that. Not until.

**The incentive structure is the reification of the will of the organisation**

Comment: The problem here is you've now added a strong incentive for people to vote to close questions that aren't actually duplicates, because they'll get rep for it.  Such a system would also incentivise people to vote to reopen the obvious dupes that they've answered to remove the rep penalty.  So while the current incentive system is indeed broken, you've just changed how it would be broken.

Comment: @Servy: You could ameliorate that problem by only giving rep if the OP agrees that the post is a duplicate.

Comment: @sumelic Now you're back to it being easier to just post an answer, as it'll get you more rep for less work, than trying to convince the OP to close the question as a duplicate.

Comment: Removing reputation from closed question has been suggested already, but there were some made-up reasons (like 'don't penalize people when "good" questions closed later as dupe or whatever' or 'people would need to think before answering; unacceptable' (exaggerated)) so people can still keep their precious reputation points. I guess the discussion about removing rep points from deleted posts was similarly dragging.

Comment: You only need *one* person with a gold badge in the tag to close a question as a duplicate.  As for reopening, as mentioned, you've now changed the incentives dramatically.  People who got rep for closing it won't want to reopen it even if they later realize the question isn't a dupe, and people who answered it are incentivised to vote to reopen even if it *is* a dupe.  All around you're adding lots of reasons for people to vote or not vote on things other than whether the question is actually a duplicate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1117/discussion-between-ben-says-no-to-politics-on-so-and-servy).

Comment: When I was a new user to the site, I spent about half an hour answering, in good faith, what seemed like an interesting question, but then a little while later the question was closed and deleted as a duplicate.  That put me off answering any questions for a good few months, and now I never answer new questions because I don't want to waste my time.  If I found I was also losing reputation, that would be an extra kick in the teeth and would probably stop me answering at all.

Answer (score -5):

For what it's worth, if anyone wishes to call me a whore - either for rep or otherwise - I find this acceptable. I cannot guarantee a third party won't moderate our communication regardless, but i'm just going on-record as saying I do not feel people who say this to me are breaking any sort of social contract. I will not accept **intimidation**, **name-calling**, or **nastiness**; but if i'm being **whore-like**, **whorish**, or just generally **whorey**, then please do call me out on it. It's much better that I stop than I continue in ignorance.

I'm not going to give a short and long version of why this is the socially responsible thing to do, instead i'll make 2 points:

1. I have seen the word 'whore' many times on the internet, and 99.999% of the time it was used for it's more modern definition - that of someone doing something unpleasant for some unrelated gain. Yes it might have started with sex for money, but these days it could be posts for rep, moderation for power, click-bait for ad revenue, etc. To stop using this word's new definition because that new definition has become more popular than the original definition will only, in my opinion, preserve the nastiness of the original definition and in the process we will lose a useful adjective.
2. This one is a little harder to explain, but essentially, SE in its current form is really rather good at moderating intimidation, name-calling and nastiness. That is because the whole context of the interaction is right there for all to see, mods can be summoned near-instantaneously to pass judgement, and most of the time they do so very well. This is important, because when it comes to nastiness context is everything. To ban a word regardless of it's context is anti-logical, anti-social, and ultimately anti-progressive. People *must* have the freedom to offend others, and to ultimately be banned for it. SE is fundamentally a democratic website, and for some words to be banned due to a technicality before they can go through the democratic process of *being read* would be at odds with the site's culture.

Comment: If the meaning of a word actually changes to a more positive one, that's cool. However, the fact that you see it as having changed in that way doesn't really make it so. Plenty of people still use it with intent to offend, and many people still find it offensive. So sure, you can tell everyone that you're okay being called a whore. But you don't get to decide that everyone else should be okay with it.

Comment: Banning a word is deciding what everyone else shouldn't be okay with.

Comment: No, it's simply acknowledging that enough people aren't okay with it.

Answer (score -8):

I've never used the term *rep-whore* and I agree that it sounds pejorative and belittling. Those who answer off-topic questions just to earn a few tens of  reputation points should be called *SE user* because we did it one way or another in the past. However, what do you call a user who constantly answer off-topic questions?

The linked question was posted on English Language and Usage, [What's a less offensive substitute for “rep-whores”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/226736/whats-a-less-offensive-substitute-for-rep-whores) and it suggests multiple alternatives.

(In order of the number of upvotes)

> Rep-hound
>
> Rep-farmer
>
> Rep-junkie
>
> Rep-monger
>
> Rep-minded
>
> Rep-reaper
>
> Rep-chaser
>
> ...

Comment: You don't call the **user** anything. See [this comment on the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281787/it-s-time-to-retire-the-term-rep-whore#comment915310_281787)

Comment: The real issue is not using the word "whore" but the fact that we're name-calling and that earning rep / liking to earn rep / doing this for rep is not bad. It's just someone's motivation. By removing use of this verb, they want to look at what can be abused or considered unfair. Please read the main post.

Comment: Why do I care what you think of the word? I'm trying to convey actual meaning when I participate on meta.

Comment: @ChrisF Who are you to tell me what to do and what not to do? Where are you from?

Comment: @Rathony He's a moderator on like half the SE sites. So be careful who you pick your fights with.

Comment: @Mysticial What makes you think I am trying to pick a fight with ChrisF? What does his being a moderator have to do with any comment I make? Do you mean I need to fear him/her just because (s)he is a moderator of a half of the SE sites? What is going on on Stack Exchange?

Comment: @HDE226868 Well, how does "You don't call the **user** anything." sound? I was being sarcastic about the question which tries to retire a perfectly well defined and broadly used word adding many other words users can choose from when they feel reluctant to use the word *rep-whore*. I don't think I have missed anything. This is closer to censorship than expanding "be nice" policy and Stack Exchange should be better than that. I have never seen the word used directly towards a user. Have you?

Comment: I've seen the term used plenty to refer to specific users. If you haven't, maybe the sites you frequent are better behaved than some, or mods have cleaned up quickly. See also Shog's answer. This is a well defined but offensive term, and telling people use it is just an explicit, public application of Be Nice, not censorship.

Comment: @Jefromi You can't stop the gun violence by just saying "Don't use a gun.". You have to make an environment where using a gun is not necessary. Just retiring the word doesn't prevent rep-hounds from trying to earn reputation points from questions normal SE users are busy downvoting and close-voting. Then, what should we do? I think Seth's answer hits the nail.

Comment: @Rathony It's not either/or. There are as always issues with the sites that need to be addressed, and there are *also* in this case people being less than nice about how they raise those issues. So what should we do? Keep fighting to fix the issues, but do it respectfully.

Comment: @Jefromi Yes, of course, respectfully. But **not** by telling the users what to do and what not to do. We have mechanisms to deal with offensive words.

Comment: @Rathony Think of this as a public clarification that this term isn't okay and we're going to start consistently applying those mechanisms, plus some additional food for thought about constructive discourse. I agree that ideally we shouldn't have to post specific advice about specific words. Unfortunately this term was tolerated to some extent in the past, and some people still think it's okay, so it merits a little extra attention.

Comment: For the record, I've deleted a lot of comments where someone was called this as an insult. They were clearly intended as insults, were flagged as such, and were removed by moderators (or more recently, the system itself). You don't see many of them because they are actively removed. Even on Meta.SO, we commonly delete comments containing this because they are usually intended to insult or demean certain people.

Comment: ... [Rep-pretty-woman](http://i.stack.imgur.com/rsiXM.jpg) (inspired apparently by this very announcement)

Comment: Jefromi - the notion that if Rathony hasn't seen anyone call anyone else a whore must be because moderation is so good, is like saying Thor must have been a great god because there are no more Ice Giants. Yes, that's one explanation - the other is that there was no Ice Giants (or whorepidemic) to begin with. If you plan on enforcing the removal of specific words, you must provide a list of words that are to be banned, and then immediately delete it because it contains those words. After all, fairness doesn't seem to be the aim here. It's all about censorship.

Comment: @J.J And it's a correct explanation. Multiple mods and CMs here have said so. People have been using the term as an insult and to harass people, and that's not okay.

Comment: @ChrisF: If you're calling a user's actions to be "rep-whoring", aren't you calling that user a "rep-whore"? (In other words, what's the difference?). Imo, naming the action or the user are both the same.

Comment: @Cerbrus not really. You can say someone is posting what looks like spam without calling them a spammer. The same applies here.

Comment: One heavily implies the other, though. If someone posts spam, that person _is_ a spammer. I guess what I'm trying to say is that it shouldn't matter if someone's calling the action something, or the person. Otherwise, _"You are acting like a d*\**k"_ is fine, while _"You are a d***k"_ isn't. I'd say, treat both types of insults the same way.