# Shotgun users that post multiple low quality answers

Tags: discussion, answer-quality

Let's suppose I'm a new user (below 1500 reputation points), and all I want to do is gain reputation points so I use the shotgun approach and answer as many questions as I can.

While I'm doing that I'm generating low-quality one-sentence answers that get flagged and deleted on a daily basis. I see a few people telling me that this isn't the best way to answer questions, but I'm on a mission to gain reputation points so I keep blasting away (there are several users that fit this description in the last 2 months).

What is to prevent me from having this kind of behavior forever?

One thing I'd also like to add is the there seems to be a process problem with dealing with these types of people, so my options are:

1. Flag the post
2. Downvote

If I downvote, and it meets the low quality criteria, then the post shows up for moderation and gets deleted (probably). I assume that since it's a deleted post, the user gets their reputation points back. If this is the case then there is no recourse for the user; if their post is bad enough it ends up being a good thing for them, and they get their reputation points back.

If I flag then there is a high probability that the post gets deleted. I assume that they get a message in their inbox (or I hope they would), but these types of users are good at ignoring the community anyway.

I'd also like to add that these users are not just posting one-sentence answers; they are repeatedly posting questions as answers and rarely use the comment system. They also don't improve their answers.

Comment: Should we shotgun them with bird- or buck-shot, Sir?

Comment: Related, a mod gives a good breakdown of the automated system here: http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/4389/30031

Answer (score 4):

Short version: Apply downvotes and flags to low quality answers.

The only mechanism within the Stack Exchange framework that works against users<sup>1</sup> who post low-quality answers is the [answer ban](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans) (or A-ban for short). The inner workings behind the A-ban are undisclosed by the Stack Exchange team<sup>2</sup>, and they probably change to keep up with times.

In practice, the A-ban affects only the beginners. For example, a new user treats Stack Exchange as a forum, posts questions as answers, and gets A-banned. In order to affect a somewhat established cheap<sup>3</sup> rep whore, he would have to receive a lot of downvotes.

<sup>1</sup> Users accounts, rather than posts.

<sup>2</sup> Similarly, I'm reluctant to share what little I know about it.

<sup>3</sup> In case you are wondering, a *cheap* rep whore posts poor quality answers, a *fine* rep whore posts high quality answers to low quality questions.

Comment: By the way, I did apply downvotes to a few of them (only the worst answers). I must have hit my limit because I got flagged and the system (or mod) removed the downvotes (I probably had 13 or so.)

Comment: @laptop2d  The system probably viewed your downvote streak as revenge-downvoting.

Comment: It pretty much was, but revenge for the right reasons

Comment: We are [not allowed to use that word](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281787/it-s-time-to-retire-the-term-rep-whore) any more...