# Idiot's Guide to the Electorate Badge?

Tags: support, badges, voting, badge-progress

Ok. So I've read multiple questions and answers on the progress for this badge and I'm still no wiser.

Repeating

> It's simple, isn't it?

Isn't really making it easier to understand.

So I'd like to ask this yet again, in the form of a picture:

[image]

What do I need to upvote in order to get this badge.

How many questions do I need to upvote? (I assume zero)
How many answers do I need to upvote?
Do the answer votes need to be on separate threads?

You may pretend that I'm an idiot, because I am...

Comment: Why would you assume you need to vote on zero questions when the description of the badge begins with "vote on 600 questions..."?

Comment: Because the "37/25 percent on questions" implies that I've over-exceeded one of the parameters.

Comment: And that matters what? You obviously haven't voted on 600 questions, yet.

Comment: the description says "25% *or more*", it doesn't matter if it goes over. Just vote on 600 questions and make sure that percentage is at least 25. It really is that simple. See the answer to [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188732/307988)

Comment: The 37/25 means 37% of your votes are on questions. The requirement is to have 25%. All is good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How many questions do I need to upvote? (I assume zero)

At least 600, as the picture says. You have votes on 391 questions now.

> How many answers do I need to upvote?

None. But every time you do, it counts against the question/answer vote percentage. That percentage must be at least 25% for questions and (at most) 75% for answers.

> Do the answer votes need to be on separate threads?

No.

As a side note: downvotes count too, so don't just focus on upvoting good content.

Comment: Ok.  So this is good.  So if I'm being a badge-badger, I need to **only** upvote questions from now on and ignore answers?

Comment: Yes, indeed....

Comment: Ah, got it.  Thank you so much.

Comment: I think the w word is not really acceptable here any more https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281787/it-s-time-to-retire-the-term-rep-whore

Comment: It's not 600 *upvotes* that are needed, it's 600 *votes* (upvotes or downvotes). So if you upvote 300 questions and downvote 300 questions, you can also get the badge.

Comment: @DonaldDuck of course. Updated.

Answer (score 4):

You should vote on minimum **600** questions.

It doesn't matter whether you voted on answer or not but when compared with the total votes, minimum **25%** votes should be on questions.

So casting **minimum 600 votes on question** and **maximum 1800 votes on answers** can help you earn this badge.

If you casted more votes on answers, you have to reach the percentage 25 (25% votes on question) to get this badge.

> As of now, you're ok with the percentage

Cast votes on 209 questions and you will get the badge