# Is it not OK to tell someone to delete their question/answer?

Tags: discussion, comments, deleted-answers

Recently I've been approached by a moderator, telling me

> you have no right to tell people to delete their questions, comments or answers.

Most of time I tell to delete the answer, here are some recent examples:

- [What is the difference between bindParam and bindValue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179874/what-is-the-difference-between-bindparam-and-bindvalue/42937623#comment86149225_42937623)
- [Get the first element of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921421/get-the-first-element-of-an-array/48410351#comment86162372_48410351)
- [Is it possible for mysqli_insert_id to return an incorrect id in high traffic applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9315200/is-it-possible-for-mysqli-insert-id-to-return-an-incorrect-id-in-high-traffic-ap/49558247#comment86126172_49558247)

I am also telling people to delete the question as well, if it turns out to be off topic, as the OP could do it single-handed, while you scarcely can get the question closed/deleted the regular way. Here is a recent example as well

[PDO call MySQL stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49487317/pdo-call-mysql-stored-procedure#comment85984581_49487317)

Honestly, I had no idea I have no right to tell people so. I have a honest impression that bad answers, as well as off topic questions are better to be deleted. Why can't I tell someone to delete their question, comment or answer?

Comment: Advising other users of how they can constructively improve their posts is more than welcome. *Courteously and professionally* advising others of why their solution may be wrong and even unsalvageable is also fine. That's not what you did. What you did was *order* people to delete their content, using rude and belittling language, in many now deleted comments. If you can't contribute constructively, we cannot accept your contributions.

Comment: One cannot improve an essentially wrong answer. All they can do is to duplicate an existing answer, which itself is a reason to delete

Answer (score 41):

As you *insist* on dragging this out into public, and people have already put time into talking about it (I was just going to delete this rant) ...

#### No, it's not okay to bully people. Telling someone to delete their contribution is just being rude. Nicely pointing out what's wrong with it can be constructive *if* you consider the person's feelings.

## And as inconvenient as it might be to you, people have feelings, and you need to be more careful with them.

I'm, at this point, sick of explaining to you why your behavior isn't welcome here, as are the moderators. If you think the site is so riddled with problems, or so irredeemable, or so annoying or offensive to the general sensibilities that shape your daily experience ...

## Leave.

If one, and I mean *one* more moderator has to waste time dealing with you again, ***leaving will no longer be a choice you can opt to not take.***

I can't put it any more clearly. We're no longer having a conversation because we're tired of listening to you. Only your actions will be considered going forward.

Comment: I see. Stack Overflow is about feelings, not knowledge. You made it essentially hypocritical site, claiming it is "not a forum" by your empty declarations, but having it a forum de facto, with thousands OT and dupe posts a day, each an easy prey for rep-whores looking for typos and coming up with wild guesses. That makes a mayhem of a site with no way to put it in order knowledge-wise, so all your poor moderators are left to do is to keep politesse. There are other sites on the network where moderators don't have any complaints. Think of it. Isn't there your part in this situation as well.

Comment: To make it clear: I do not deny the fact I misbehave. Too much incompetence is driving me nuts, that's true. It's a cumulative effect. I can explain a folly or two all right, and can do it much better than most people and you know it. But when I get surrounded by incompetence from every direction and get no help the authorities but only "none of your business" suggestions, it goes out of control. So I do agree that it's not ok to bully people. Make SO less attractive for the answers out of nowhere and quality control better than current ochlocracy and there will be less problems with politesse

Comment: I would vote this up until about 3 years ago when I figured that all these talks about feelings and niceness are accompanied by permanently [ignoring embarrassment of core group users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281807/165773). "Yeah we make it easier for low quality content flood the site and you just have to learn to live with it and keep being nice" (that said @Your advising deletion is too tedious to do right because too many categories of users simply can't do that, starting from those on mobile. I for one don't do this because I don't want to waste time on checking and tracking)

Comment: I've upvoted your answer here _@Tim_, because I've seen @YCS failing that many times at MSO with publishing their opinions at MSO. But TBH, leaving  them with the statement **LEAVE.**, isn't very much better than what you're claiming now is annoying about them. I'm well aware, that there might have been a number of discussions between (SO) site moderators, before taking the decision to ban YCS for a year (not to mention that the user name is a provocation at all). Hypocrisy in terms of just serving _"Joel Spolsky"_ 's business needs, might be a serious point, which needs discussion.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ keep in mind that's not the first time YCS is suspended. I think he got that at least twice before, and always came back just to repeat the same rude behavior. At some point, even the most patient people lose their patience.

Comment: @Shadow **I do not** "come to repeat the rude behavior". Saying that would be a blatant slander and dishonesty. You have a biased view, which could be understood as you only meet me in certain circumstances, but in reality it's not what I am coming for. What I am coming for is to help people, and I can assure you, there are a hundredfold more satisfied people than ones who felt insulted or pretended so. Whatever rudeness is a slipping, not a purpose. Please keep that in mind.

Comment: @YourCommonSense that’s part of the problem though - helping 100 people doesn’t excuse insulting or being rude to the 101st. There are plenty of similarly passionate people frequenting the network, equally frustrated with the perceived state of things, also helping hundreds of people, that aren’t semi-regularly brought to task for their treatment of other users. Your knowledge, experience and what seems to be dedication mean you’re potentially one of the top assets SO could have. Why can’t you just play nice too? Then you’d be the full package

Comment: @Clive, nowhere did I say it does excuse. I just pointed out that saying I am coming for being rude is not a correct statement. As to whether I can be nice boils down to "we will keep the site this way and you either live thith it or leave". I would have think of cooperation if there was a hint from the site management they will too.

Comment: Nope, not buying it. The choice to be nice lies entirely with you, just like everybody else here. You can dislike policies, you can dislike individuals, but you can’t respond to that by lashing out at strangers. Your actions are **your** responsibility. Not the staff, not the moderators, not the people who post bad content. Just yours. The attitude of _I’ll be nice if you do what I want, but I won’t otherwise_, is not one that belongs in civilised society, and frankly you only have yourself to blame for how this has ended up

Comment: @Clive I agree with you on that. I should have said "As to whether I plan to participate on this site...". And may be add that making the rules less ambiguous and less mutual exclusive would soften the tensions as well.

Answer (score 13):

I think we can sometimes help new users understand how things work here, and explain to them it is better to delete an obvious wrong or 'NAA' answer.

I don't think it is necessary to do so on a large scale. A heavily down-voted question could count as a reason to advise deletion.

In one of the answers you linked, the user thinks the answer is okay, and with a score of +7/-6 it seems that the community is divided, but in favor of the answer. I think advising to delete is wrong here. It is unnecessary and not your responsibility to do so.

If you technically disagree, just downvote and move on. The voting itself should be a strong enough message you think the answer should go. There is no need for a comment telling so.

Comment: The problem with some answers there, they are heavily *upvoted*...

Comment: Then you disagree with the majority (maybe you are right, maybe not). Then still you should not advise to delete.

Comment: There is no "may be". When I have no idea on the matter, I just keep my mouth shut.

Comment: Then just downvote, comment the answer is wrong and why and move on.

Comment: **Now please delete your comment because it is wrong** (pun intended)

Comment: Ok I see. The usual I don't care attitude.

Comment: It seems you have the "I am always right" attitude. Sometimes you're wrong. There is no point in arguing, so please let's don't do that.

Comment: Sometimes I am, yes. It has nothing to do with the question asked.

Comment: @YourCommonSense it has everything to do with the question asked. Since you're not always right, and since you ask about posts having upvotes which means other users think in a different way than you, it is not OK to tell the author of that post to delete it just because you think it is wrong.

Comment: I leave an explanation as well. A sensible person would read and comprehend. But wait, I said sensible, on Stack Overflow? Nevermind.

Comment: @YourCommonSense and yet again, you assume you're the only one who has sense, and all others are stupid. You have full right to think this way, but when it slips through to comments and come (naturally) as offensive, flags rise and moderators are involved.

Comment: An irony, you don't have a knowledge to tell whether I am right or wrong about particular answers, all you have is an assumption that I *could* be wrong. Yet you are accusing me as though I am always wrong.

Comment: @YourCommonSense *I leave an explanation as well. A sensible person would read and comprehend.* you mean the ones where you call answers a hoax or useless (sometimes in all capitals),  tell people to grow up or otherwise belittle the poster? Pretty sure they have been read and comprehended as rude - as they are. You can advise people removing a post might be a good idea but you don't get to demand it along with snide insults.

Comment: @JonClements rudeness is one thing and asking people to delete their post with an explanation is another. I didn't ask whether rude comments are good or not, thank you for trying to help.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I'm pleased you've suddenly become aware there's a difference between those two now. It's a shame so many comments have had to be cleared up where apparently you didn't.

Comment: @JonClements that's the only job moderators have, so they shouldn't complain. Were they more focused on the content than on the politesse, thee would have been less rudeness as well. You are making SO a garbage pile and take a pride in keeping garbage in proper lines.

Comment: @YourCommonSense "asking people to delete their post with an explanation" is misrepresenting what you were doing, and I think you know it. You were abusive and rude to numerous people, often telling people they "must" delete their answer, while calling their answer "fraud" and "a hoax" and accusing people of posting only for reputation, and offering *no* explanation as to why you were *ordering* people to delete their content.

Comment: @YourCommonSense - You do understand that community moderators are volunteers, right?

Comment: @meagar the question is not what I am doing but whether it's ok to ask someone to delete their post. Thank you for trying to help

Comment: @Ramhound I do. I do also understand the essentially hypoctitical nature of Stack Overflow, that make moderators perform a duty they aren't supposed to do. Were it less aimed to attracting clueless people with off topic questions and wrong answers, and more aimed for quality, were wouldn't be so much burden for moderators as well

Answer (score 6):

No it isn't.

I'm a moderator on a slightly smaller site than SO, and am familiar with the approaches and problems have.

I've personally been somewhat annoyed at questions that are off topic, or just bad. We get spillover from SO question-banned folks here and on SU, and I've never once told them to delete their question. (Before I was a moderator, I've managed to convince a spammer to self delete but on hindsight that was somewhat mean to someone who was probably just a minimum wage drone).

As a more experienced user - I've always felt there's an obligation to *guide* users towards the right way. I've never told folk to delete even explicitly off topic questions.

I have this odd theory that most community and human interactions have parallels in dog training. What you're basically saying is about the same that it's perfectly right to shove a puppy's nose in its own poo, for doing toilet in the wrong place. The right way is to show said puppy that there are better places, and ways to do things. *Positive* reinforcement works better than *negative* reinforcement.

Back to people.

I've always started *any* critique of a post with "Welcome to _____", especially if it's a new user. I'd point out the specific *places for improvement* "this question could do with more details such as". In short point them at the right place and way to do things.

If I'm closing "I'm voting to close/I've closed this but you can improve the post". If I'm deleting I go "You can always fix these issues and flag for reopening".

At no point do I tell people "You must delete this post".

Looking at the other two posts here from Tim and Patrick, I'd probably follow up with another observation - that you need to consider the same standards you're hoping others follow - that there's not much difference between trying to deal with problem questions by asking them to delete and problem behaviour by suggesting the user go away until one can refrain from consistently problematic behaviour.

> I do not deny the fact I misbehave. Too much incompetence is driving me nuts, that's true. It's a cumulative effect.

That's a sign you might need to decompress a little.

If you *must* deal with a tide of low quality posts - why not be constructive about it? Vote and Delete. Raise specific, actionable issues on meta. Work *with* people rather than wandering around the dark alleys of SO, pouncing on the unweary in an attempt to scare off 'undesirables'?

Comment: Actually, the last suggestion contributes A LOT to that desperate feeling. When you see your vote goes for nought, and never gets to delete, and when you see posts on Meta for ages, which everyone agrees with,  but NOT A BLOODY THING ever done in practice, it drives you nuts as well.

Comment: *Constructive*. I've had bad days. I've had days where I wanted to metaphorically tear someone a new one. I stepped away from the keyboard, walked my dog, played some games... I'd say that commenting *isn't* helping you at all, is undermining the mods and others and well,isn't actually creating the change you want to see. What *have* your comments achieved so far?

Comment: Actually, some time ago I voluntarily  banned myself from commenting. Got accusations of sitting a high horse and being contemptuous.

Comment: If so... how exactly did the events that triggered this post off happen?

Comment: Well, it's a long story. I've been suspended and I'd say it was rather justified as of recent I indeed allowed myself some personal attacks and unwelcome tone. I wouldn't expect such a long term though, especially given that some of previous bans weren't justified at all (it was like "OK, you're not guilty but we'll keep it anyway"). Anyway, it was not my concern at all. What caught my eye in the moderators message is a sentence cited in my post, and I was genuinely puzzled as to whether indeed I cannot ask someone to delete their question.

Comment: Well, clearly this is a specific issue that you're expected to address in terms of "be nice". As a mod, I sometimes find people have problems seeing where there's issues and need guidance of a more pointed source. I do believe you're expected to cease since you're not doing it in a manner that the moderation, and I suppose community management team find is in line with the rules of the community.

Comment: An I find the rules of the community a crock of you know what. So we sort of agree on that :)